RLException: Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]:
I am using ROS noetic to run Turtlebot simulation in gazebo environment. I cloned the repository turtlebot and turtlebot simulator. When I ran the command roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
I received an error as follows
`... logging to /home/abc/.ros/log/0fbbba6c-49ec-11ef-bb1f-7b777aa12b2b/roslaunch-megatron-15084.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
/usr/bin/rosversion:6: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
/usr/bin/rosversion:6: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
resource not found: kobuki_description
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/noetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/abc/ROS_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/noetic/share
when processing file: /home/abc/ROS_ws/src/turtlebot/turtlebot_description/robots/kobuki_hexagons_astra.urdf.xacro
RLException: while processing /home/abc/ROS_ws/src/turtlebot_simulator/turtlebot_gazebo/launch/includes/kobuki.launch.xml:
Invalid  tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [['/opt/ros/noetic/lib/xacro/xacro', '/home/abc/ROS_ws/src/turtlebot/turtlebot_description/robots/kobuki_hexagons_astra.urdf.xacro']] returned with code [2].
Param xml is 
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
`
The code block of  kobuki.launch.xml is
<launch>
<arg name="base"/>
<arg name="stacks"/>
<arg name="3d_sensor"/>
<arg name="urdf_file" default="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(find turtlebot_description)/robots/$(arg base)_$(arg stacks)_$(arg 3d_sensor).urdf.xacro'"/>
<param name="robot_description" command="$(arg urdf_file)"/>
<!--  Gazebo model spawner  -->
<node name="spawn_turtlebot_model" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="$(optenv ROBOT_INITIAL_POSE) -unpause -urdf -param robot_description -model mobile_base"/>
<!--  Velocity muxer  -->
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="mobile_base_nodelet_manager" args="manager"/>
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="cmd_vel_mux" args="load yocs_cmd_vel_mux/CmdVelMuxNodelet mobile_base_nodelet_manager">
<param name="yaml_cfg_file" value="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/param/mux.yaml"/>
<remap from="cmd_vel_mux/output" to="mobile_base/commands/velocity"/>
</node>
<!--  Bumper/cliff to pointcloud (not working, as it needs sensors/core messages)  -->
<include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/includes/kobuki/bumper2pc.launch.xml"/>
</launch>

The code block for kobuki_hexagons_astra.urdf.xacro is
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
    - Base      : kobuki
    - Stacks    : hexagons
    - 3d Sensor : astra
-->    
<robot name="turtlebot" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <xacro:include filename="$(find turtlebot_description)/urdf/turtlebot_common_library.urdf.xacro" />
  <xacro:include filename="$(find kobuki_description)/urdf/kobuki.urdf.xacro" />
  <xacro:include filename="$(find turtlebot_description)/urdf/stacks/hexagons.urdf.xacro"/>
  <xacro:include filename="$(find turtlebot_description)/urdf/sensors/astra.urdf.xacro"/>
  
  <xacro:kobuki/>
  <xacro:stack_hexagons parent="base_link"/>
  <xacro:sensor_astra   parent="base_link"/>
</robot>

The code block of is
import xacro
xacro.main()

How can I solve the error?
```

